# Searching from up voted posts

Tags: support, search

How can I search for text within my up-voted but not self-questioned or self-answered posts?

For eg: `user:me is:upvoted "asyncio"`.

Comment: `score:x` will get all posts with a score of x or more

Comment: am looking to filter just my upvoted posts, not scores collected from all.

Comment: Then @reservoirinvest do `score:1 user:me`. It's not perfect because it checks score and not upvotes but I think there's a way to do it with SEDE.

Comment: The search box doesn't support criteria for "has upvote" or "has downvote". This needs [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

This [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1425212?search=asyncio&UserId=7978112) will do that for you:

```sql
select p.id [Post Link]
     , upvotes
     , p.score
     , p.posttypeid
     , p.creationdate
     , p.closeddate
from (
select p.id
     , count(*) [upvotes]
from posts p
inner join votes v 
   on  p.id = v.postid 
   and votetypeid = 2 --upmod
where owneruserid = ##userid?7978112##
and body like concat('%', ##search:string?asyncio##, '%')
group by p.id
) mp
inner join posts p on mp.id = p.id
order by upvotes desc
```

When run today that gives you two results:

[image]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the magnificent [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).